# jQuery filters sometimes showing all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I toggle between jQuery filters that show elements with a certain class, sometimes the selected filter shows all elements and not just the ones with the respective class.

You can see this in the below fiddle. Switch between the select options and sometimes they'll show all results.

[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/emturano/gmuq0kxw/1/)

```
function activateButtons(_data){
  $('.jobs-teams select').on("change", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    for(i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
        var teamRaw = _data[i].title;
      var team = cleanString(teamRaw);
      var jobs = $(".jobs-list");
      if ($(this).find(":selected").hasClass(team)) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("active")) { 
          $(this).removeClass("active");
          jobs.find(".job").fadeIn("fast");
        }
        else {
          $(".jobs-teams").find("a").removeClass("active");
          $(this).addClass("active");
          jobs.find("."+team).fadeIn("fast");
          jobs.find(".job").not("."+team).fadeOut("fast");
        }
      } 
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I never thought you'll also ask another question about this. :) i'll lend you a hand.

Comment: Not just sometimes--every other select change.

Comment: you are almost there, you just need to edit some stuffs :) I posted an answer below check it :).

Comment: I think we all need to edit "some stuffs" :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues with the code that just need to be updated are the following.

```
//$(this) return the select tag. you should target options
if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
   $(this).removeClass("active");
   jobs.find(".job").fadeIn("fast");
}
else {
   //$(".jobs-teams").find("a") returns undefined remember that you changed the anchors to select options
   $(".jobs-teams").find("a").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
   jobs.find("."+team).fadeIn("fast");
   jobs.find(".job").not("."+team).fadeOut("fast");
}
```

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```js
// Replace "leverdemo" with your own company name
url = 'https://api.lever.co/v0/postings/leverdemo?group=team&mode=json'

//Functions for checking if the variable is unspecified
function cleanString(string) {
  if (string) {
    var cleanString = string.replace(/\s+/ig, "");
    return cleanString;
  }
  else {
    return "Uncategorized";
  }
}

function nullCheck(string) {
  if (!string) {
    var result = 'Uncategorized'
    return result;
  }
  else { 
    return string;
  }
}

function createJobs(_data) {
  for(i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
    
    var team = nullCheck(_data[i].title)
    var teamCleanString = cleanString(team);
$('#jobs-container .jobs-teams select').append(
   '<option value="" class=' + teamCleanString + '>' + team + '</option>'
);
  }

  for(i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < _data[i].postings.length; j ++) {
      var posting = _data[i].postings[j] 
      var title = posting.text
      var description = posting.description  
      //Making each job description shorter than 250 characters
      var shortDescription = $.trim(description).substring(0, 250)
      .replace('\n', ' ') + "...";
      var location = nullCheck(posting.categories.location);
      var locationCleanString = cleanString(location);
      var commitment = nullCheck(posting.categories.commitment);
      var commitmentCleanString = cleanString(commitment);
      var team = nullCheck(posting.categories.team);
      var teamCleanString = cleanString(team);
      var link = posting.hostedUrl;
    
     $('#jobs-container .jobs-list').append(
      '<div class="job '+teamCleanString+' '+locationCleanString+' '+commitmentCleanString+'">' +
        '<a class="job-title" href="'+link+'"">'+title+'</a>' +
        '<p class="tags"><span>'+team+'</span><span>'+location+'</span><span>'+commitment+'</span></p>' +
        '<p class="description">'+shortDescription+'</p>' +
        '<a class="btn" href="'+link+'">Learn more</a>' +
      '</div>'  
    
      );
    }
  }
}

function activateButtons(_data){
  $('.jobs-teams select').on("change", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    for(i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
     var teamRaw = _data[i].title;
      var team = cleanString(teamRaw);
      var jobs = $(".jobs-list");
      var $this = $(this).find(":selected");
      if ($this.hasClass(team)) {
       if ($this.hasClass("active")) { 
          $this.removeClass("active");
          jobs.find(".job").fadeIn("fast");
        }
        else {
        
          $(".jobs-teams select").find("option").removeClass("active");
          $this.addClass("active");
          jobs.find("."+team).fadeIn("fast");
          jobs.find(".job").not("."+team).fadeOut("fast");
        }
      } 
    }
  }).change();
}

//Fetching job postings from Lever's postings API
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  success: function(data){
    createJobs(data);
    activateButtons(data);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
  
p {
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
}
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.job {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 40px 30px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #454545;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
.job-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #454545;
}

.job-title:hover {
  color: #00A0DF; 
}

.tags span {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: grayMediumDark;
}
.tags span:after {
  content: ', ';
}
.tags span:last-of-type:after {
  content: '';
}
.description {
  color: #999;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #999;
  border: 2px solid #ebebeb;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #ebebeb;
  color: #555;
}
.btn.active {
  background: #454545;
  border-color: #454545;
  color: #fff;
}
.jobs-teams {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 0 30px
}
.jobs-teams .btn {
  margin: 0 8px 8px 0;
}
.jobs-teams .btn:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.jobs-teams .btn:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container" id="jobs-container">
    <h1>Open jobs</h1>
    <div class="jobs-teams">
      <select>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="jobs-list">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider doing it with fewer lines:

```
function activateButtons(_data) {
  $('.jobs-teams select').on("change", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var selected_class = $('.jobs-teams select').find(':selected').attr('class');
      $('.jobs-list').find('div.job')
        .not('.' + selected_class).fadeOut('fast').end() //remove the ones that do not match
        .filter('.' + selected_class).not(':visible').fadeIn('fast'); // bring in the ones that do match (and are not already visible)
    })
    .change(); //have the form pre-load with the default selected value
}
```

Oh--I also added a line to have the jobs honor the default selection (`.change(); //have the form pre-load with the default selected value`).

[Working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/6v6qwjf1/)

Comment: there is a problem with this in the first on change event. :)